# Firefox: select item in long dropdown list using search

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I have to select an item in a dropdown select list which has 4000 items (options) in it. Typing the first letters helps, but it would really help if I could use search for this. The default search function doesn't find anything in this list, as well as the [**FindBar Tweak**](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/) add-on.

The [**Find in this SelectBox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/find-in-this-selectbox/) addon is not supported anymore.

**Is there a way to select an item in a select list using search?**

If another browser can do this, that might work as well. I'm on Ubuntu currently, can move to Mac if needed.

Comment: What about to see the source code of the page (Ctrl-U) and search in it with (Ctrl-F)? Moreover under Firefox (Ctrl-Shif-C) you can open the  Firebug Inspect Elemen even if I suppose it will be easily useful in you case.

Comment: I want to select it, then use it to submit the form. Just searching for it is not enough.

Comment: It was just a workaround, Ctrl-U, Ctrl-F then search& find Ctrl-C (in memory) Ctrl-W (to close) Ctrl-V to paste... In some page there are active css (?) that allow you to search in this kind of lists (Ctrl-F when you are inside)... but it is page dependent and I understand what you are searching for. It should be cosy.

Comment: "I have to select an item in a dropdown select list which has 4000 items (options) in it." that is extremely poor interface design. Change the UI.

Comment: @DavidPostill - this is not my website! I cannot change the design. I can install a plugin or use other tricks, but that is a useless suggestion. I'm the user, not the developer.

Answer (score 0):

simply type more than the first letter .. works for me in both google-chrome and mozilla-firefox.

EDIT:
Okay, then there's really just this bookmarklet you could use. Select the select. Click the bookmarklet - probably twice, to close the open select and then actually activate the bookmarklet - enter the beginnings of the value and get placed at the first occurence that matches.

```
javascript:(function(){dae=document.activeElement;if(dae.nodeName=="SELECT"){oa=dae.options,st=prompt("search term");st=st.toUpperCase();for(x=0;x<oa.length;x++){opt=oa[x];if(opt.value.substring(0,st.length).toUpperCase()==st){dae.selectedIndex=x;}}}})();
```

Comment: This is what I currently do, but there are many items with the same first four to even ten characters. I can type up to four characters quickly, depending on the word, and I'm starting to discover that slower typing works even better, but not too slow. What I want is to press CTRL-F or right-click the item, then paste the search term, then press submit.